# Can exclude some attribute in one node in the return value of a XPATH query

Tags: select, xpath, attributes

The case is

```
<a>
   <p id="1" userName="administrator" password="xxx" />
</a>
```

If I use "/a/p" as xpath query, then it will return

```
<p id="1" userName="administrator" password="xxx" />
```

However, I just want to display attribute id and userName, how could I do that?

Besides, I don't want to use any xpath standard function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `@` at the beginning of attribute name to address an attribute in XPath, for example :

```
/a/p/@id
```

or to get both `id` and `userName` at once :

```
/a/p/@*[name() = 'id' or name() = 'userName']
```

or if you meant to get all attributes excluding `password` (since you have 'exclude' tag in question) :

```
/a/p/@*[name() != 'password']
```

**UPDATE :**

Responding to your comment, there is actually a very limited workaround in XPath 1.0 using `concat()` function :

```
concat(/a/p/@*[name() = 'id'], ', ', /a/p/@*[name() = 'userName'])
```

Comment: However, it will result in two lines, I just hope the two attributes displayed in one line.

Comment: that's only possible if you're using XPath 2.0 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974253/xpath-concat-multiple-nodes

Comment: check my update for the best XPath 1.0 can do to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

XPath (1.0 or 2.0) can only return nodes that were present in your input document, it cannot create new or modified nodes. For that you need XSLT or XQuery.

You can return strings, numbers, or booleans that are constructed from the nodes in the input document - but doing so without use of any standard functions sounds like masochism.